# bluetooth headphones paired, connected not appearing as sound device

Tags: audio, bluetooth

Arch MATE up to date

Not blocked

```
rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

From the bluetooth session

```
 [JBL LIVE400BT-LE]# info 71:7D:D8:A5:A4:C8
 Device 71:7D:D8:A5:A4:C8 (public)
    Name: JBL LIVE400BT-LE
    Alias: JBL LIVE400BT-LE
    Paired: yes
    Trusted: yes
    Blocked: no
    Connected: yes
    LegacyPairing: no
```

pavucontrol GUI shows only the laptop's sound card.

aplay says this

```
 :> aplay -l
 **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
 card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC668 Analog [ALC668 Analog]
   Subdevices: 0/1
   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
 card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
   Subdevices: 1/1
   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
 card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
   Subdevices: 1/1
   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
 card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
   Subdevices: 1/1
   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
 card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
   Subdevices: 1/1
   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
 card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
   Subdevices: 1/1
   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: Try installing: pulseaudio-alsa, pulseaudio-bluetooth and bluez-utils.

Comment: @CinaedSimson  Yup. I did all this https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/bluetooth_headset